# Convert Excel File to Json Object in React

Tags: json, excel, reactjs

I'm quite new to React. I need to convert the Excel Data (.xlsx) file to JSON object within react. Can someone suggest any react components to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can search on [https://www.npmjs.com/](https://www.npmjs.com/) for some helper libraries/component

Comment: Found it, thank you.